# How to load Image as binary image with threshold in Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a grayscale image--the MNIST dataset, actually--and I need to convert it to a binary image with a threshold of, say, 240 so that all values below 240 are ones and all values above are zeros.

This is a function in matlab, so I'm sure there is some corresponding function in scipy...but it is eluding my searches.

---

Equivalently, if I have a (60000,28,28) shaped ndarray, how to I conditionally inspect all of the values and set values above 240 to zero and the rest to 1?

In pseudo-numpy code,

```
image_array = big_array_of_28x28_images

bw_image_array = image_array[image_array > 240 yield 0, else yield 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is your matrix, the binary matrix B is:

B = np.where(A <= 240, 1, 0)